# Kivy hello world example not working windows10

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to run the basic example from the Kivy documentation (using python 3.10.4, vscode and windows 10):

```py
import kivy
kivy.require('2.1.0') 

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App): 
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')

if __name__ == ' main ': 
    MyApp().run()
```

When i run, the following output is showed at the terminal:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Julio Cesar\.kivy\logs\kivy_22-12-23_7.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.4.5
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Julio Cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Julio Cesar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
PS C:\Users\Julio Cesar\Documents\Códigos Python\ilgui>
```

But from what i saw, it was supposed to generate a window with the given string. And that is not happening here, just this output and then the terminal command line shows again.
Anyone can enlighten me? Thanks in advance.

I tried uninstalling kivy and python.

Comment: you just have a typo on line 11, `main` needs dunder syntax: `if __name__ == '__main__':`, then your example should work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much, i just copied from the documentation and didn't paid attention. Life saver

Comment: Typos usually receive down votes on questions, because they don't fall in line with SO guidelines for asking a "good" question. I don't know what to really suggest what to do with this question - delete it(?), close it(?), do nothing(?), beats me. That being said: Hi, welcome to stack overflow, be sure to check out the [how to ask a good question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your if statement where you said `if __name__ == ' main '` you need to add double underscores before and after ' main ' to fix this issue.

just like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    MyApp().run()
```